# Rails controller scaffold code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scaffolding

for a university project I'm looking to make some changes to the Rails scaffolding mechanism. Mainly, I want to know where controller scaffold code is generated.

When looking at where the code is generated I found what looked like the appropriate bits here: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/scaffold_controller/templates/controller.rb.tt

However, after changing it, it doesn't seem to make a difference. I tried both `rails g scaffold ....` and `rails g scaffold_controller ...`.

I also noticed that the code that I end up with looks different from what I would expect from the template.

template:

```
# PATCH/PUT <%= route_url %>/1
def update
  if @<%= orm_instance.update("#{singular_table_name}_params") %>
    redirect_to <%= redirect_resource_name %>, notice: <%= "'#{human_name} was successfully updated.'" %>
  else
    render :edit
  end
end
```

reality (dogs_controller.rb):

```
# PATCH/PUT /dogs/1
# PATCH/PUT /dogs/1.json
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @dog.update(dog_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @dog, notice: 'Dog was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @dog }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @dog.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

So mainly the generated code also responds to json requests, while the template does not look like it respects that.

The scaffolding console output also claims to `invoke  scaffold_controller`.

Then there's also the code here: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/controller/templates/controller.rb.tt but that is even more bare bones.

Long story short, am I doing something wrong or where is the controller code for scaffolding generated.

FYI I cloned rails at commit a1f9fe8bdd4e6c4e20fbda424c0ecf2f31fabd30 and branched of from there, so fairly recently.

Comment: when `ack`ing for "# PATCH/PUT" I basically only find those code bits :(

Comment: That is, indeed, curious.

Comment: Can I suggest that instead of cloning Rails. That you do this the intended way. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html#customizing-your-workflow-by-changing-generators-templates It should solve any of the goathas' or things left out of the post.